# Haskell: searching though fst in a tuple and displaying the snd

Tags: haskell

I have a database of films like so:

```
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner", "Ridley Scott", 1982, [("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)]),
("The Fly", "David Cronenberg", 1986, [("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",5)])]
```

It contains two films in the format: 'title', 'director', 'year', 'user rating'

```
type UserRating = [(String, Int)]
```

I have a function called 'displayAllFilms' which will display each film in a formatted string.
and a function 'hasUserRated' which returns a Bool if a user has rated:

```
hasUserRated :: String -> Film -> Bool
hasUserRated user (_, _, _, userrating)
        | elem user (map fst (userrating)) = True
        | otherwise                        = False
```

If I do: `displayAllFilms $ filter (hasUserRated "Amy") database`
It will return all the films that Amy has rated (Blade Runner & The Fly)

I need to also display what the rating was when it finds Amy's tuple.

To tackle this I have a function called `whatUserRated`:

```
    whatUserRated ::  String -> Film -> [Int]
    whatUserRated user (_, _, _, userrating)
         | elem user (map fst (userrating)) = map snd userrating
```

my question:

I need to change the above function to just return one int, the int of the 'snd' in the tuple where the element 'user' (amy) is found. i.e
I would need to:

WhatUserRated "Amy" (I need the result of the filter to be the second parameter)

The below function is so you can see it in context:

```
userRatedFilms :: String -> Database -> String
userRatedFilms user database = displayAllFilms $ map (whatUserRated "Amy") $ filter (hasUserRated "Amy") testDatabase
```

So far, the above will return all the ratings in the films that Amy has rated,

However, I want only her ratings.
I hope I have explained this enough, my English is not excellent.

Thank you,

Mike.

Answer (score 4):

The function you're looking for is called `lookup`.  It has the type

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

Basically, it takes an association list and returns the first result where the given key matches the first element in one of the tuples.  If no such tuple is found, it returns `Nothing`.  An example usage would be

```
> lookup 3 [(1, "One"), (2, "Two"), (3, "Three")]
Just "Three"
> lookup 4 [(1, "One"), (2, "Two"), (3, "Three")]
Nothing
```

One of the handy things about the `Maybe` data type is that you can use it to filter as well as look up data.  If the operation returns `Nothing`, discard it, otherwise use the value.  For example, you could write your functions as

```
whatUserRated :: String -> Film -> Maybe Int
whatUserRated = user (_, _, _, userrating) = lookup user userrating

hasUserRated :: String -> Film -> Bool
hasUserRated user film = isJust $ whatUserRated user film
```

Just make sure to import `Data.Maybe`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [lookup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3alookup):

```
whatUserRated ::  String -> Film -> Maybe Int
whatUserRated user (_, _, _, userrating) = lookup user userrating
```

whatUserRated now returns Maybe Int, becuase it is possible that a user didn't rate a specific film (which means you don't need to check it first).

The second function is now simplified to:

```
userRatedFilms :: String -> Database -> String
userRatedFilms user database = displayAllFilms $ mapMaybe (whatUserRated user) testDatabase
```

[mapMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v%3amapMaybe) takes a list of maybe values and returns only the ones that actually contains data (the `Just` values). You'll need to add `import Data.Maybe` to get mapMaybe.